# How to use an app.config file when calling a C# dll from C++

Tags: c#, .net, c++, interop, app-config

How do I use an `app.config` file for the .Net part when calling a .Net dll from C++ and the data in the config-file must be read at the .Net runtime startup.

If I use have a `foo.dll.config` that I call from `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("foo.dll")` I can access application settings. What I would like to do though is to change some information in `<system.data>`, namely remove a `DbProviderFactory` and replace it with a new one.

It seems like this can only be done if the code is put in the exectubales `app.config` file.

But as I am calling the .Net code from C++, I cannot have an app.config for my executable.

Is there some way to specify a configuration file that is sure to be run right after `machine.config` when the .Net runtime starts, even though I'm calling the .Net dll through C++?

Answer (score 4):

You can have myapp.exe.config, and the called .Net assembly will use it, even if myapp.exe is c++ app. I have done this using outlook.exe.config for my outlook addin.